# Processes performed during MacOS installation

Tags: macos, install

I wonder on what so much time is spent during installation or upgrade to new MacOS. In other words: having strongest machine (MacbookPro) with fastest hard drive (1GB/s read/write abilities) and having fast internet connection (30Mbps) - why update between two consequent minor version (i.e. from 10.12.2 to 10.12.3) takes 30 minutes - even if update declared to be 800 MB in size. I expect in answers mentioning specific functional actions, if someone knows or can guess ones.

Comment: The time to update dot releases is carefully chosen by Apple developers to give you a decent break to make and drink a cup/cocktail glass of coffee/tea/Vodka-Martini, tidy up your desktop and water (or talk to) your indoor plants. It's completely independent of the built-in hardware like processors or hard drives and always takes ~thirty minutes. Please check this in the preflight and post-flight scripts accompanying all macOS updates.

Comment: I'll start a CW list.  I can only think of one thing right now but I'm pretty sure others can fill it out better.

Comment: @klanomath lol ---

Answer (score 1):

(If you can add anything to this list, it would be greatly appreciated.)

- **Firmware updates**
  Each and every macOS installer includes a firmware update package that has to run before the "regular" install process can be begun.

Comment: How many files involved? How many bidirectional transactions persist? Why should it take not more than 2-3 min to update dozens of files and that's all?

Comment: That's a question for smarter people than me :)